Can I attach my concrete deck footing to my foundation with rebar?
Our deck design is dramatically simplified and much stronger if we can place a post footing right at the corner of our house.
This post footing would be closer than 3 feet (actually, just 3 or 4 inches) away from the foundation so building codes call for that footer to be as deep as the foundation itself.
But a problem is that the corner of the foundation is a pier that goes down ten feet. We really don't want to undermine the pier and we also don't want to dig deeper than 10 feet to meet that code....but we really need that post to be there.
Can we dig the footing as deep as it would be specified if it's not next to the foundation and then drill some rebar INTO the foundation with epoxy and CONNECT the deck pier to the foundation??
Or perhaps we don't need to go as deep as the pier, we only need to go as deep as the rest of the foundation which would be no problem??
An edit: my foundation is around 3 feet deep but there are pilings that were simultaneously poured that go down much deeper. If the deck code says to go as deep as the foundation would it be reasonable to go down 3 feet? It's not likethe soil was disturbed along the drill path all the way down to 10 feet deep....

I think it's likely that the section of code you refer to is intended to prevent having a situation where you have a shallow footing subject to frost heave placed right next to a deep footing, and having them negatively interact with each other somehow. So my guess is that it would meet code if your new footing is as deep as the rest of your foundation, not necessarily as deep as that 10' pier.

@brhans Thank you--that is my own thought as well. Also no frost here so that is not an issue.

Updating this for posterity---I have read more that convinces me attaching a pier or block or footing, with rebar, drilled into your foundation is a BAD idea. If you have any differential settling at all, the rebar you drill into the foundation can cause cracks, water intrusion, further expansion...etc. So basically you are weakening your foundation if the two concrete bodies settle at different rates at all.

My engineer had similar concerns about my deck footing where my wall goes down 16' and then he decided it was of course stupid to put a deck footing down 16' and that the loading on the deck and increased lateral loading of the soil supporting the deck footing was never going to be an issue for the lateral strength of the foundation wall.
I just have pad footings on backfill and they go down just far enough for frost line for the deck.  Unsurprisingly the foundation wall is as solid as ever and the house has not collapsed.

We were contemplating an addition to our house.  The architect said the pilings had to go all the way down to the footer and bear on the footer,  The reason he gave is that the soil near the existing foundation was backfilled after the footers and foundation wall were built, and even after many years, may not be fully compacted.

@stevesh sure but you can build a raft foundation on mud with less bearing capacity than your potentially not fully compacted dirt.  There are alternate design options.  architect != engineer so they won't be able to offer alternatives as easily.  I typically have to push the engineers to give alternate options.  the default easy no need to think answer is put it on undisturbed soil at the same level as the adjacent footing and sometimes that is the cheapest/easiest option if you already have a digger onsite.

@SteveSh just to be clear - when you say your "wall does down 16'" you are talking about your foundation, correct ? How far down do those pad footings you mention go??

Yes foundation wall goes down 16'.  Deck pad footings were just put down to frost level 24" from grade to the bottom but they were 24"x24"x12" pads with an 8" column coming up to support my deck beams.

The issue is that many (most?) jurisdictions want deck footings to bear on undisturbed soil.  Obviously that's not always possible on a construction site, but I'd hazard a guess that most foundation backfill isn't structural fill, i.e. compacted to a density that will support a structure.  If I couldn't guarantee that the soil was structurallly sound, IDK that I'd be OK going down less than the foundation depth for deck footings.

@Huesmann Yes-understood. But if our foundation corner is a drilled pier ten feet lower than the foundation its not like the nearby earth was disturbed by construction activity ALL the way down to minus-13 feet. I am leaning towards going deeper than the foundation (but not deeper than the pier) and calling it a day.

At the end of the day this is a deck, it isn't a house.  Decks structures are supposed to be inspected every few years given their exposure to the elements.  Even if the footing for the deck does settle and start to dip you can always just jack it up and adjust the post of the affected area.  You don't necessarily want to do this but the risk should be low.  In this scenario I'd just make the pad wider to increase the soil bearing surface - go with a 3x3 pad.

@user227963 right, what I'm saying is that you probably don't need to excavate down to the bottom of your pier, because soil below the top of your pier is likely undisturbed.  You may need to excavate to the bottom of your wall for any deck footings close to the house, because the soil adjacent to the wall was undoubtedly backfilled.  Any deck footings further away from the house probably only need to go down to the frost line, because the backfill area probably doesn't extend that far.
